# How to connect to bluetooth services like PBAB with Qt?

Tags: qt, bluetooth

I am trying to read contacts from my phone to my Linux machine using Qt application. I am only able to pair my phone, but unable to connect / read contacts from it. In fact I'm not sure about the exact api to be used to connect to PBAB profile.
I found samples using dbus to connect to PBAB profile and read contacts. But I would like to know if QBluetooth module support the same if so how to use it.

Hope somebody can help me out in this case.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: There's a Qt add-on called Qt Bluetooth, so what excatly is your question?

Comment: @classstacker: is this some thing different than the module added by giving `QT += bluetooth` in pro file?